# Not using a class in python, but my function requires a "self" argument?

Tags: python, class, self

I am trying to use these functions to calculate heat capacities with tabulated data, however it get an error unless I run the second function with a "self" argument.

```
TypeError: integral() takes exactly 6 arguments (7 given)
```

I did some searching and it seems that you need the "self" argument when using classes, but I have not created any classes. Only two functions. Anyone have any idea what is going on?

```
from scipy.integrate import quad

def heatcap(T, a, b, c, d):
    a1=a*10**-3
    b1=b*10**-5
    c1=c*10**-8
    d1=d*10**-12
    return a1+b1*T+c1*T**2+d1*T**3

def integral(self, a2, b2, c2, d2, T1, T2):
    I=quad(heatcap, T1, T2, args=(a2,b2,c2,d2))
    print I
```

Comment: `self` is just a name. Somewhere in your code, this function is getting passed an argument you're not expecting, but that argument doesn't necessarily mean what you've concluded it means.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't diagnose this problem with the information given. Take a look at the stack trace, see what lines it's pointing at, and see if any of those lines pass arguments you didn't expect. If you're passing `integral` as a callback to some other function, look at the documentation for that other function and see what arguments it passes to `integral`.

Comment: Your code doesn't show how you're using those functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use self inside a class, like this:

```
class myClass:
    def myFunc(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

When used as an argument to a function outside a class, `self` does`t have any special meaning; it's just an argument named self. Thuogh you should really not name your arguments self, as it can be very confusing.

As your function does not belong to any class, it expects you to give it 7 arguments, including the one named self.